# Access Token validation for OAuth2 flow with Service Accounts in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-app-engine-python

I am using the `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` Python client API class to generate my app access token.

I get a token only once in my app when the first request arrives. Then I use that token in every build or execute a service.
 I suppose that token will expire after some google timeout...

How I test if my token is valid in order to refresh it?

Comment: this is explained in the offcial google oauth2 guide

Comment: Hi @ZigMandel. 
In my case I'm using a Service Account with two-legged flow (server-to-server) OAuth2 authentication. In that case there is no interaction with end user/browser redirection to refresh the access token.

So, I need a way to deal with token timeout/validation and refresh it when necessary.